# How to delete everything outside the clipping mask?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, clipping-mask

My goal is to delete everything outside the clipping mask.

What I've tried:

1. Put an image.
2. Create a shape on top of the image.
3. Create clipping mask with `Object > Clipping Mask > Make`
4. Select the `Clip Group`.
5. Open `Pathfinder` window with `Window > Pathfinder`.
6. Select `Crop` from the `Pathfinder`.

The problem:

1. I got message `The filter produced no results. Please select two filled and overlapping path`.

I am confused because on YouTube, I did the exact step-by-step. The only difference instead of deleting shape, I am deleting image outside the clipping mask.

Comment: Is the "image" a **raster** image? Your process *won't* work on placed *raster* images. I believe newer versions of Illustrator have the ability to crop raster images. Failing that... try using `Object > Flatten Transparency` rather than Pathfinder.

Comment: If you are using a newer version of Illustrator, see here: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/crop.html

Comment: I believe the image is raster / `import image from a folder to Illustrator`. I tried `Object > Flatten Transparency` with `the shape is on top of the image`. However, the image outside the `Shape` is not deleted.

Comment: @Scott the `crop` is the way to go. Thank you.

Comment: One has to create the Clipping Mask, *then* use Flatten Transparency. I'm glad merely the crop work for you `:)`